# Why can't I see attachments to comments in the array-shift profile of Drupal?

Tags: drupal, attachment

Why can't I see attachments to comments in the array-shift profile of Drupal? When I used the Array Shift theme in the array-shift profile of Drupal, I can't view attachments in the comments, but if I switch the theme to Garland, I can magically see the attachment then. Why? How can I get the array-shift theme to display the attachments, too? I've tried tinkering with views, template files, admin settings all with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Garland theme was using a field rowstyle, which showed the attachment table, and the array-shift theme was using a node rowstyle, which will not show the attachment information without coding it into the file. I had to use code like this:

echo $field_attachment[0]['filename'];

in the node.comment.tpl.php file. Using the devel module showed me exactly what field names to reference for this.